# Doctrine findBy() on MySQL with columns with Special characters

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I Have a MySQL table with the following abbreviated description.

```
+-----------------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                             | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                                | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| trailer_number                    | varchar(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| discount_structure (%)            | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| net_purchase_price                | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| capitalised_extras                | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| maximum_write-off_period (Months) | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| maximum_write-off_period (KMS)    | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| residual_value (%)                | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| interest_rate (%)                 | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| insurance (%)                     | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| coastal_wholesale_price_of_fuel   | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

in order to handle the `(%)` etc in the column names I have to use backticks in the SQL calls eg.

```
SELECT 
    t0.trailer_number AS trailer_number_1, 
    t0.`discount_structure (%)` AS discount_structure_68, 
    t0.net_purchase_price AS net_purchase_price_69, 
    t0.capitalised_extras AS capitalised_extras_70, 
    t0.`maximum_write-off_period (Months)` AS maximum_writeoff_periodMonths_71, 
    t0.`maximum_write-off_period (KMS)` AS maximum_writeoff_periodKMS_72, 
    t0.`residual_value (%)` AS residual_value_73, 
    t0.`interest_rate (%)` AS interest_rate_74, 
    t0.`insurance (%)` AS insurance_75, 
    t0.coastal_wholesale_price_of_fuel AS coastal_wholesale_price_of_fuel_76, 
    t0.id AS id_77 
FROM fox.trailer t0 WHERE t0.deleted = 0
```

In my entity I've added the backticks to my column name e.g.

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="`discount_structure (%)`", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=false)
 */
private $discountStructure;
```

When I do a call

`$trailers = $this->em->getRepository('FoxBundle:Trailer')->findBydeleted(0);`

I get the following error

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\SyntaxErrorException]                                                                                                                                                                                            
  An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.trailer_number AS trailer_number_1,t0.discount_structure (%) AS discount_structure_68, t0.net_purchase_price AS net_purchase_price_69, t0.capitalised_extras AS capitalised_extras_70, t0.maximum_write-off_period (Months) AS maximum_writeoff_periodMonths_71, t0.maximum_write-off_period (KMS) AS maximum_writeoff_periodKMS_72, t0.residual_value (%) AS residual_value_73, t0.interest_rate (%) AS interest_rate_74, t0.insurance (%) AS insurance_75, t0.coastal_wholesale_price_of_fuel AS coastal_wholesale_price_of_fuel_76, t0.id AS id_77 FROM trailer t0 WHERE t0.deleted = ?' with params [0]:                                                                                                                                                                      

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%) AS discount_structure_68, t0.net_purchase_price AS net_purchase_price_69, t0.' at line 1
```

I don't own the database so I can't change the column names. 
Is there anything else that I can do so that findBy() functions work?

Comment: This isn't an answer in as much as know how to solve your error but in a way to avoid these things which is if you just used simple names (which is adviced anyways) you woudn't have any problems. Just keep it flat a-z/_ no fancy symbols. You can even suffix simple names with things like _percentage _months if you really wanted to.

Comment: @JennevanderMeer I would halve also only used alphnumeric characters but I didn't create the database and only have READ Access to it so I can't change the column names.

Comment: I just did a small test `name="\`name (%)\`"` and a findAll which works fine, so i don't think thats the problem, what does the repo function findBydeleted do?

Comment: @JennevanderMeer just tested that findAll() also works for me. the findByColumnName("parameter") allows you to filter by specific criteria. In my case I want the records that haven't been flagged as deleted(i.e. deleted = false). I'm not sure how it actually does this in the background.

Comment: Im unable to reproduce this even adding a deleted property to my test entity and doing findByDeleted just works. Im afraid you have to do some real deep digging in the stacktrace / symfony debug toolbar, it could tell you more (you can see query details if you click the icon). One tiny thing you could also try (which I don't think changes anything internally) is try `... ->findBy(['deleted' => 0]);` and maybe update? my test instance is from like 2 weeks ago. But I've never really had to go this deep so other then this I'm also out of ideas

Comment: It seems to be working correctly now. I think it may have been because I cleared the cache since I first tested it. `php bin/console cache:clear` `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` `php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`  `php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query` `php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding backticks to your entity column names does work.

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="`discount_structure (%)`", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=false)
 */
private $discountStructure;
```

you must just remember to clear the Cache.

```
php bin/console cache:clear 
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod 
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query 
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```